# Is there a way to jump pages with a tweepy cursor?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get followers from a big account using tweepy.
When the job was half done, something gone wrong and I had to start again.

I'd like to know if there is a way to jump directly to page X and avoid reiterating all the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`search` method](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#help-methods) accepts a parameter `page` which can be used to jump to a particular page (in combination with `rpp`). If you are using `Cursor`, these parameters can be passed as named parameters to its constructor, i.e., `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, page = ...)`

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this though I am not sure it is the optimal one. If you use tweepy.Cursor class to get followers, you can first define a cursor instance:

```
my_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, count=200)
```

Then launch the streaming by looping on:

```
my_cursor.items()
```

You can access the current page cursor value at any moment by doing:

```
my_cursor.next_cursor
```

If you want to restart from approximately the same point where streaming stopped, just do:

```
my_new_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, count=200, 
                              cursor=my_cursor.next_cursor)
```